# iPhone: run Automation tests on Simulator

Tags: iphone

I’ve been using the new UI automation tools with Instruments and the iPhone SDK 4.0, but so far I haven’t been able to get it to run under the iPhone Simulator.

For some people work solution like this:

> "Copy ~/Library/Application Support/iPhone
>   Simulator/4.0/Library/Preferences/com.apple.Accessibility.plist to
>   ~/Library/Application Support/iPhone
>   Simulator/4.0.1/Library/Preferences"

But i don't have folder ~/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/4.0
. I have 4.0.2, 4.3 4.3.2..And they don't com.apple.Accessibility.plist. What to do ? Thanks...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

./Library is hidden folder in OS X Lion.
To show hidden file see [this](http://www.mikesel.info/show-hidden-files-mac-os-x-10-7-lion/)

Comment: I have such folder, I don't have simulator 4.0

Comment: Just look your application for which target it is build for and then move to that iOS version. And you can find /Library/Preferences

Comment: ~/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/<Your Application Build Version>/Library/Preferences